# Django/vanilla javascript ajax posts successfully but the page still reloads

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Ajax submitting a form works, but I'm unable to stop the page reload.

I've tried several variations of event listening by id. On the form, the button, tried using inline onclick, onsubmit, tried putting the button outside of the form.

```html
<form method="post" id="form1">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|crispy }}
      <button type="submit">Click</button>
    </form>
```

```
function parse_cookies() {
    var cookies = {};
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        document.cookie.split(';').forEach(function (c) {
            var m = c.trim().match(/(\w+)=(.*)/);
            if(m !== undefined) {
                cookies[m[1]] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
            }
        });
    }
    return cookies;
}
var cookies = parse_cookies();

var title = document.getElementById('title_identifier');

function ajax_function() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", `/ajax_post_function/${title.textContent}/`, true);
  request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
  var formElement = document.querySelector("#id_comment");
  request.send(new FormData(formElement));
}

form = document.getElementById('form1')
form.addEventListener('submit', ajax_function)
```

If I change the event handler from the form to the button or vice versa, it posts successfully with the message shown in chrome dev tools being:
(1)

```
VM667 ajax_post_function.js:22 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/ajax_post_function/WhateverTitle/".

Navigated to http://localhost:8000/ajax_post_function/WhateverTitle/
```

But it just goes back to the top of the page again.

However, If I use this ajax function, then the comment is not submitted, and the response from the chrome dev tools is:

```
function ajax_function(e) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", `/ajax_post_function/${title.textContent}/`, true);
  request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
  var formElement = document.querySelector("#id_comment");
  request.send(new FormData(formElement));
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```
ajax_post_function.js:34 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/ajax_post_function/WhateverTitle/".
```

If I use:

```
return false;
```

in either version of the ajax_function,
The form submits successfully, but reloads again and returns to the top of the page, with the message in chrome dev tools being the same as in the (1) example.

I've been using shift + f5 in between changes as cache busting. I'd rather not use jquery.

The view function serving the route is long(ish) and I'm not sure if it's relevant so I didn't post it here. Ajax posts to the same route it's on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#form1').on('submit',function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open("POST", `/ajax_post_function/${title.textContent}/`, true);
 request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', cookies['csrftoken']);
 var formElement = document.querySelector("#id_comment");
 request.send(new FormData(formElement));
 }
}
```